# Função sendo executada duas vezes jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$("#salvar_festa").click(function() {

    var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();
    var id_pacote = $("#id_pacote").val();
    var tipo_reserva = $("#tipo_reserva").val();
    var data_evento = $("#data_evento").val();

    var itens = "";
    $('.checados').each(function(){
        var tmp = this.value.split("|");
        var v = tmp[1],
            result = 0;
        v = v.toFloat();            
        itens += v +";";
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: basePath + 'evento/salvar_festa',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            id_cliente: id_cliente,
            id_pacote: id_pacote,
            tipo_reserva: tipo_reserva,
            itens: itens,
            data_evento: data_evento
        },
    })
    .done(function(ret) {
        console.log("success");
        $('#mensagePage').html(ret);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    }); 

});
```

Ele salva normal no banco de dados, porém, salva duplicado.
Eu colocando um alert no inicio, como este:

```
$("#salvar_festa").click(function() {
    alert('teste');
```

Ele aparece dois alerts, quando clica.

Alguém consegue me dizer onde está o erro?

**EDIT - JQUERY QUE CHAMA pacotes_lista_itens**

```
$(".pacote").change(function() {
    var pacote = $(".pacote").val();
    var data = $("#data").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: basePath + 'evento/get_pacotes_item',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            pacote: pacote,
            data: data
        },
    })
    .done(function(ret) {
        console.log("success");
        $('.pacotes_lista_itens').html(ret);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

});
```

**EDIT HTML**

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['data']; ?>">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <label>Selecione o Cliente</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="id_cliente" name="id_cliente">
                    <option value="0">Selcione um Cliente</option>
                    <?php foreach($lista_clientes as $valor){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $valor->id; ?>"><?php echo $valor->nome_responsavel; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <label>Selecione o Pacote</label>
                <select class="form-control pacote" id="id_pacote" name="id_pacote">
                    <option value="0">Selcione um Pacote</option>
                    <?php foreach($lista_pacotes as $valor){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $valor->id; ?>"><?php echo $valor->nome; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="pacotes_lista_itens"></div>
            </div>  

            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <br/>
                <button id="salvar_festa" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
                <button onClick="close()" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Posta o HTML do elemento

Comment: Tens a certeza que essa linha `$("#salvar_festa").click(function() {` só aparece uma vez no código?

Comment: Pois o html....

Comment: @Sergio sim tenho certeza, porque eu chamei a função em um lugar só, e se eu deletar tudo que tem dentro da função, e deixar só o alert, ele duplica o alert também...

Comment: Postei também o jQuery que chama a página para completar o formulário.

Comment: Tenta dar um $("#salvar_festa").off("click"); antes de atribuir o click

Comment: Deu certo @Sorack muito obrigado, salvou o dia pesquisando rsrs

Comment: Vou postar a resposta pra você aprovar e ajudar alguém que procure a mesma coisa, beleza?

Comment: Ótimo, em 5 minutos aceito sua resposta. não permite antes, mas deu certíssimo!

Comment: Consegues reproduzir o problema num jsFiddle?

Comment: Tente usar um return antes de fechar a função do click. `return false;`

Comment: Se caso não funcionar, posta o código que salva as info no banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar eventos duplicados utilize o seguinte código antes de atribuir o click:

```
$("#salvar_festa").off("click")
```

E tente atribuir o click da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on("click", "#salvar_festa", clicar);
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema, esconde-o.

Comment: Puts, @Sergio rs, agora lascou então, pode ser que tenha algo a ver com angular js? porque o sistema tem esse negocio de angular mas não entendo nada disso :\

Comment: @AndréBaill algo está a duplicar esse click. Vê nas ferramentas de dev quais os "event handlers" ligados a esse elemento e de que linha de código vêm.

Comment: Onde eu acho isto?

Comment: Viu, faz o que o sérgio falou e da uma olhada na segunda parte da resposta que eu dei

Comment: Tô tentando verificar pra eu saber certinho de onde vem esse clique extra..

Answer (score -3):

*Fala pessoa!!*

Caso seu código Jquery esteja sendo executado 2x, uma possível solução seria colocar o código **fora da função $(document).ready(function(){**

espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).